# Effectively gather data with small differences

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, gathering

I frequently encounter themes where I have a set of data, then I need to gather up those identical ones. However, due to numerical error in data, `GatherBy` cannot be directly implemented, while `Gather` seems too slow.

Take this case as an example: I have a set of 2D points, i.e. `pts={{0.,0.},{1.,1.},{2.,1.},{2.0001,1.0001},{1.0049,0.},{1.0051,0.}}`, and I need to gather up those points which represent the same thing under a tolerance of approximately 0.01 unit.

A natual solution is `Gather[pts,Norm[#1-#2]<.01&]`, however `Gather` suffers from performance issue when the list is large. Another natural solution is `GatherBy[pts,Round[#,0.01]&]`, however this is not correct, the last two elements should be gathered together while in this method, they are not.

FYI: A possible implementation is as follows, however I fear that this might be too slow, so I'm asking are there any built-in function which can serve this purpose or are there any better implementation.

```
TolerantGatherBy[list_, f_, fdiff_] := 
 Module[{k, current = <||>, temp, fval},
  Do[If[fval = f[i]; 
    temp = SelectFirst[Keys@current, fdiff[fval, #] &, k]; temp === k,
     AppendTo[current, f[i] -> {i}], 
    AppendTo[current[temp], i]], {i, list}];
  Values@current
  ]

TolerantGatherBy[pts, Identity, Norm[#1 - #2] <= 0.01 &]
```

Or if I want to find out the index of those gathered together, I can write:

```
TolerantGatherBy[Range@Length@pts, pts[[#]] &, Norm[#1 - #2] <= 0.01 &]
```

I would like a solution which is similar to the performance of GatherBy while accepting tolerance.

Answer (score 9):

[`ClusteringComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusteringComponents.html) does what you want; maybe play with the [`DistanceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceFunction.html) and other options:

```
ClusteringComponents[pts, Length[pts], 1]

(*    {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}    *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, I will look into it! BTW, is this complicated function efficient comparing to Gather/GatherBy?

Comment: @Wjx before you worry about performance, you should worry about algorithmic stability. `Gather` assumes that your criterion is transitive (some kind of equality). But as your criterion is not transitive (i.e., it can easily be that A is close to B and B is close to C, but A is not close to C), you need some general way to look for clusters.

Comment: I'm aware of this issue, but in my use case the error is small. Stability is not a issue as long as the cluster's size is always smaller than half the threshold I use. if A is close to B, B is close to C, then A will be close to C.

Comment: So `GatherBy[pts, Round]`?

Comment: Check the example in the question~, `GatherBy[pts,Round]` could be incorrect when two data points are 0.4999 and 0.5001.

Comment: It seems that `ClusteringComponents` is somewhat reluctant to let us setting the `CriteriaFunction`, I made several attemps but all failed, can you elaborate on that? Thanks!

Comment: @Wjx the rounding grid has to be adapted to your numbers. The numbers you have provided previously were roundable to an integer grid; your new numbers are roundable to a half-integer grid. Just pick the appropriate rounding grid. If you could provide your entire list of numbers, someone here could help you with fine-tuning.

Comment: in my actual use case I'm trying to merge similar points in a randomly generated `MeshRegion`, so I would like to have a more universal solution. In my answer I provided a viable solution for this particular case of gathering points.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for this particular case of gathering index of points which are near to other points:

```
PointGatherBy[pts_, tol_] := 
 Values@PositionIndex@
   Merge[Flatten[
     MapIndexed[Function[s, s -> {Length@#1, #2[[1]]}] /@ #1 &, 
      Flatten[Values[
          PositionIndex[
           Round[Transpose[Transpose[pts] + #], tol]]] & /@ 
        Tuples[{0, tol/2}, Length@pts[[1]]], 1]], 1], 
    TakeLargestBy[#, First, 1][[1, -1]] &]
```

performance check:

```
n = 2000;
pts = Join[RandomReal[0.001, {n, 2}] + #, #] &@RandomReal[100, {n, 2}];

Gather[Range@Length@pts, 
   Norm[pts[[#1]] - pts[[#2]]] <= .01 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
TolerantGatherBy[Range@Length@pts, pts[[#]] &, 
   Norm[#1 - #2] <= 0.01 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
PointGatherBy[pts, 0.01]; // AbsoluteTiming
ClusteringComponents[pts, Length[pts], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {16.9512, Null}
>
> {15.7348, Null}
>
> {0.242784, Null}
>
> {57.5847, Null}